# What does the Torque vs Frequency plot mean for a stepper motor

Tags: torque, stepper-motor

I found [this motor](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/nmb-technologies-corporation/23KM-K267-00V/P14277-ND/2417001) which I believed had interesting specs, but when I checked out the data sheet, the torque-speed graph was replaced by a torque-frequency graph! I do not know what it means. How does it intuitively translate to torque at a given speed?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The datasheet you linked list rotational speed (r/min) as the secondary value on the horizontal axis below frequency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RPM of a stepper motor](https://www.se.com/id/en/faqs/FA337686/)

> Formula for calculating stepping motor speed.
>
> $$RPM = \dfrac{a}{360} \cdot f_z \cdot 60$$
>
> $RPM$ = Revolutions per minute.
> $a$ = step angle
> $f_z$ = pulse frequency in hertz